# Submitting Laravel Livewire form crashes another component

Tags: laravel, web, tailwind-css, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have an add component, that is essentially a pop-up window with form. When I click the submit, the display component, that shows the data deletes from the page. Not even dispatch even dispatch even pops it back on.

The display component is just foreach loop inside a table. In the view the components are just on top of each other.

It shows no errors in console, all requests, that are supposed to be sent are sent. But the table just dissapears.

Add component methods for creating new entity:

```
public function storeWork()
{
    $this->validate();
    $this->time_from = new DateTime($this->date .' '.$this->day_start);
    list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $this->length);
    $this->time_to = (clone $this->time_from)->add(new DateInterval("PT{$hours}H{$minutes}M"));
    $work = $this->create();
    $this->dispatch('refreshList');
    session()->flash('success', 'Výkaz byl přidán.');
    $this->addNext();
}

public function render(){
    $orders = Order::where('state', "nevyrizena")->get();
    $employees = Employee::all();
    return view('livewire.WorkAddComponent', [
        'orders' => $orders, 
        'employees' => $employees,
        'types' => $this->types,
        'machines' => $this->machines,
        'categories' => $this->categories,
    ]);
}
```

Add blade:

```
<div>
    <div x-data="{
        expanded: false,
        form: true,
        closeform() {
            this.expanded = false;
            this.form = true
        },
        openform() {
            this.expanded = true;
            this.form = true
        }
    }">
        <button class="btn" type="button" x-data x-on:click="openform()">
            ...
        </button>
        <div style="display: none;" x-show="expanded">
            <div class="fixed left-0 top-0 z-40 h-screen w-screen bg-gray-800/90"></div>
            <div class="fixed top-10 z-50 max-h-full w-full items-center justify-center" aria-hidden="true"
                 tabindex="-1">
                <div class="relative w-6/12 rounded-lg bg-gray-700 p-10 text-white shadow">
                    ...
                    <form wire:submit="storeWork">
                        @csrf
                        <div x-show="form">
                            <div class="mb-4">
                                ...
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-4">
                                ...
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-4">
                                ...
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-footer flex gap-3">**!!!THIS BUTTON DOESNT BRAKE IT!!!!**
                                <button class="btn" type="button" x-data
                                        x-on:click="form = false">Pokračovat</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div x-show="!form">
                            <div class="mb-4">
                                ....
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-4">
                                ...
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-4">
                                ...
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-4">
                                ...
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-4">
                                ...
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-4">
                                ...
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-footer flex gap-3"> **!!!BOTH OF THESE BREAK IT**
                                <button class="btn-second-opt" type="submit" x-data x-on:click= "closeform()">Uložit a zavřít</button>
                                <button class="btn" type="submit">Uložit a další</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                @if (session('success'))
                    ...
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Display component:

```
#[On('refreshList')]
    public function refresh(){}

    public function render()
    {
        $work = Work::where('date', $this->displayDate)->paginate(10);
        $people = Employee::all();
        return view('livewire.WorkDisplayComponent', [ 
            'work' => $work,
            'people' => $people,
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically the other component got eaten by the upper one, and during updates of the upper one, it didnt get sent back. So I did like a really dirty trick, but it works now. I just close the component element before it has chance to contain the other component.
The trick im talking about..

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    @livewire('WorkAddComponent')
    </div>
    @livewire('WorkDisplayComponent')
@endsection
```

edit.. well that was unneccessary I was just thinking, if simple /div did the trick, the DOM must be poorly structured so i looked back and in app blade i had closed one if too late so initially the component didnt close correctly on load, so livewire just put the other component inside of it, and then when it got the correct format of the component, it probably just got confused, that the element now closes without the other component, so it removed it all together.

```
<div>
        <div x-data="{...}">
            <button class="btn" type="button" x-data x-on:click="openform()">
                ...
            </button>
            <div style="display: none;" x-show="expanded">
                <div class="fixed left-0 top-0 z-40 h-screen w-screen bg-gray-800/90"></div>
                <div class="fixed top-10 z-50 max-h-full w-full items-center justify-center" aria-hidden="true"
             tabindex="-1">                     
                       ...
                        <form wire:submit="storeWork">
                            @csrf
                            <div x-show="form">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    @if (session('success'))
                        ...

                </div> THIS /DIV IS MISSING INITIALLY
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```